# Prove an Equivalent Criteria for $\sigma$-finite measures.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

A measure $\mu$ on (E,$M$) is $\sigma$-finite if and only if there exists a strictly positive function $f$ in M such that $\mu f<∞$  .

Please help me out with the proof. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/9748/5363) gives some inspiration.

Comment: Help you with **what**?  You haven't asked a question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite then there is a sequence of disjoint sets $A_n\in M$ such that $0 < \mu(A_n) < \infty$ and their union is the whole space:  $\bigcup_nA_n = E$. Define 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n\mu(A_n)}1_{A_n}(x)
$$
i.e. $f(x) = \frac{1}{2^n\mu(A_n)}$ for all $x\in A_n$. Clearly, $f$ is strictly positive and $\mu f = 1<\infty$.

Now, let there be a function $f$ which is strictly positive and $\mu f <\infty$. Define 
$$
B_n = \left\{x:\frac1n\leq f(x)\leq n\right\}.
$$
Then $B_n$ is an increasing sequence which covers the whole space $E$. Moreover, 
$$
\mu f = \int\limits_E f(x)\mu(dx)\geq \int\limits_{B_n} f(x)\mu(dx)\geq \frac1n \mu(B_n)
$$
so $\mu(B_n)\leq n(\mu f)<\infty$. If we define $A_1 = B_1$ and $A_n = B_{n+1}\setminus B_n$ we obtain a countable disjoint cover of $E$ and $\mu(A_n)<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you fore your quick answer. But I don`t know why μf=1

Comment: @user: swap integration and summation to get $$\mu(f) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n\mu(A_n)} \mu(1_{A_n}(x)) = \sum_{n\geq 1} 2^{-n} = 1.$$

Comment: @Ilya sorry this is an old comment, I have since found it :)